# UV Mapping basic cube results in rectangles instead of squares

Tags: uv

I try to UV map the standard cube created when starting Blender (v2.79).

I'm following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbj4d5XL0NA), using Cycles and have made these seams.

[image]

The cube size is standard 2x2x2 but move a little in Z-direction.

When I try to UV map it I get the following result.
[image]

Why do I get rectangles instead of squares? Is there some way to easily change it to squares?

This is the settings of the cube

[image]

Blender file

[image]

Comment: Apply scale, Object mode > Ctrl+A

Comment: @MrZak no that did not solve the problem. Scale is 1.000 on all axis It still shows up as in the image above

Comment: Scale before I applied was 1 and the same after. Did unwrap it after. Added the file now. Would be great to know what details you are looking for, but please go ahead and check the file

Comment: By lacking details I meant that this situation is often got with uneven / unapplied scale, and if not then it's not even clear what could else cause that. In your file unwrap become non-stretched (as expected) after reunwrapping (pressing U again in viewport and then Unwrap or E in UV editor). So hard to tell what could be there

Comment: Select the whole cube in edit mode, press U and select reset from the menu. Then go to object mode and press Ctrl+A and select apply scale.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Maybe changing the UV unwrap Method might help?